# How to exclude WinPhone from the build

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms application, which supports iOS, Android, and UWP. I have an issue with the latter, when I am trying to submit it to Windows Store using Azure pipeline. I keep getting an error:

> Status 400: {"code":"InvalidParameterValue","data":[],"details":[],"message":"AllowTargetFutureDeviceFamilies was not updated with all supported platform(s): [Desktop, Mobile, Xbox, Holographic]","source":"Ingestion Api","target":"allowTargetFutureDeviceFamilies"} CorrelationId: d6b9d6a2-6906-4908-9832-28c8f3c45a36

Here is how this looks at the Partner Center:

[image]

It looks like the issue has something to do with app.xap and Windows Phone. We are not supporting Windows Phone, so here is how it looks in our Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Dependencies>
   <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
   <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
</Dependencies>
```

And here is my UWP project's target plaftorm version:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

And here is some of my pipeline information:

```
steps:
- task: richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-Versioning-Task.Version-APPX-Task.VersionAPPX@2
displayName: 'Bump UWP Versions'
inputs:
  VersionNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber).0'
  InjectVersion: true

variables:
   BuildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
  - task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build project **\*UWP.csproj'
  inputs:
     solution: '**\*UWP.csproj'
     msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms=x86 
 /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\" 
 /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload'
     platform: x86
     configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
     clean: true
```

How can I submit my app? How can I get rid of Windows Phone, if that is the problem?

Comment: Which `TargetPlatformVersion` and `TargetPlatformMinVersion` do you have in UWP project?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Isn't it what I mentioned in my question?   <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
   <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" /> If it is not that, where can I find it?

Comment: I don't think that it's the same. Open properties of UWP project and check the `Targeting` section under the `Application` tab. Or check the values of the properties above manually on `csproj` file

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Oh, I see.     <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>

Comment: Well, you build it using win10 sdk only. Can you update a question with details of Azure pipeline and UWP project details. There is an interesting note, the you have `xap` file, not the `appx`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I added some information. Do you have any idea on why I am having this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Here is an error on the build: Reading SDK manifest file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsMobile\10.0.18362.0\SDKManifest.xml". Targeted configuration and architecture "Retail|x86" No FrameworkIdentity attributes were found in the SDK manifest, treating this SDK as a non-framework SDK. No "APPX" attributes indicating app package locations were found in the SDK manifest. If an app package is required at runtime the project may not run.

Comment: You'll need to check the `Retail` configuration, maybe something is wrong with it (in comparison with `Debug` or `Release`)